# Triple Integral with spherical polar coordianates

Tags: calculus, integration

> By changing into spherical coordinates (or by any other method)
>   evaluate the triple integral  $$\iiint_V xyz \ dxdydz,$$
>   where $V$ is the volume in $\mathbb{R}^3$ deifned by the inequalities
>   $$x^2+y^2+z^2\leq1, \quad x\geq0, \quad y\geq0, \quad z\geq0. $$

Could someone please explain how I would change it into spherical polar coordinates?

Comment: This is not a site for answering homework questions. If you have questions about the process, tell us what you've tried and we'll offer advice, but this is not a tutoring service.

Comment: He's not asking for the answer, he's asking for help. Yeah, its not a site for answering homework questions, but it is a site for helping people learn math which is what he is asking.

Comment: You can post photos right into the question so that they will show up without us having to click a link to view it. Also, try typesetting it with MathJax. It's not all that hard \$\iiint_V xyz \ dxdydz\$ to get $\iiint_V xyz \ dxdydz$. And it looks so awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a set of instructions that will help you calculate the integral.

I. The first step is to decipher the integral in question.

$$\iiint_V xyz \ dx dy dz=\iiint_V xyz \ dV$$

Note that I have changed it to "$dV$" because I think it is really instructive to think of it as a "volume element" as opposed to '$dxdydz$'. The volume element depends on the coordinate system you use (e.g. rectangular $(x,y,z)$ or spherical $(\rho,\theta,\phi)$).

$V$ is some 3-dimensional region, and $xyz$ is a function of 3 variables which varies its value throughout the region $V$. Sometimes, I like to think ot $V$ as a space I can walk around in, and $xyz$ could represent how the temperature changes according to where I stand.

II. The next step is to change from rectangular to spherical coordinates. This involves three things: 
(1) substitute for $x$, $y$, and $z$ the corresponding spherical parameterization. For example $x=\rho\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)$. 
(2) Substitute the spherical volume element for $dV$. You should be able to find that with some searching. Hint it is something squared times a trig function times three "$d$" factors. 
(3) Determine the correct limits of integration. Hint: what shape is $V$? How do $\rho$, $\phi$, and $\theta$ need to vary in order to 'sweep' out the entire shape?

III. Now, you should have your integral set up and the final step is to evaluate it like any other triple iterated integral.

Other recommendations:
 - I advise using a free online integral calculator app to check your work. There are many available, and you can evaluate both rectangular and spherical integrals to make sure they both give the same answer. So you should also set up the iterated rectangular integral.
 - Try the integral without $xyz$: $\iint_V dV$ (again by hand and with an online app). You should get the volume of the region $V$ (which is a standard geometric shape in this case). That way you can check that you have the correct volume element and limits of integration, and that you are taking antiderivatives correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest drawing a picture of the region you'd like to transform.  It seems to be an upper octant of the unit sphere.  Then, write down the bounds based off of the geometry of the region:

$0 \leq r \leq 1,$
$0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$

and so on.  Then all you need to do is change the xyz dx dy dz into its spherical form.  This is just substituting the definitions for what x, y, and z are in spherical coordinates, and remembering that there is a "Jacobian" factor involved in transforming dx dy dz into dr d$\theta$ $d\phi$ (the factor will be $r^2 \sin{\theta},$ depending on how you previously defined $\theta$ and $\phi).$

Hope this gives you a push in the right direction.